# Computing closed form of $\sum_{k=0}^n b^{\alpha^k}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, power-series

> Let $$\sum_{k=0}^n b^{\alpha^{k}}$$ be a sum where $b \in \mathbb N_+$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb R,  \alpha > 1$. What is its name and how can I calculate its closed form?

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n b^{\alpha^k} & = b^{\alpha^0} + b^{\alpha^1}+ b^{\alpha^2} + b^{\alpha^3}+\dots+ b^{\alpha^n} \\
& = b + b^{\alpha}+ b^{\alpha\cdot \alpha}+ b^{\alpha\cdot \alpha\cdot \alpha}+ \dots+ b^{\alpha\cdot \alpha\cdot \ldots \cdot\alpha}
\end{align}

Comment: From your original post I could not really understand if yours is a series or a finite sum, so please edit the post again if I edited incorrectly. As a series it seems to be always divergent, that is why I have this doubt. If it is a finite sum I suspect you want a closed form of it, instead of 'partial sums'. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Thanks, I made the edit. I haven't done stuff like this in a long time!

Comment: You did not edit the sum then, but I can do it.

Comment: Thanks, I missed it.

Comment: The series is always divergent under your stated conditions and would converge only if you allow $0 < b < 1$.

Comment: Does that mean there's no closed form for $n \in N+$ ?

Comment: Well, if $b$ is a prime number, then the sum does converge in the $b$-adic numbers, but that's more complicated than I'm sure you want. In the ordinary sense, there's no closed form.